# inheritance and pure virtual function in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, pure-virtual

I am not getting the desired output with this program. The warnings that I am getting are:

1. Class 'shape' has virtual method 'shap' but non-virtual destructor.
2. lass 'square' has virtual method 'shap' but non-virtual destructor.
3. Class 'rectangle' has virtual method 'shap' but non-virtual destructor.

Though the program is compiling without any errors but  i am not getting the answers that must be 20 and 18. Also i am unable to understand the meaning of these warnings. And why are the answers not being displayed on the screen? And also how should i initialize the values of length and breadth if i were to do it through a constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class shape {
    int length;
    int breadth;

public:
    int area;
    virtual int shap(int, int) = 0;
};

class square : public shape {
public:
    int shap(int length, int breadth) { return area = length * breadth; }
};

class rectangle : public shape {
public:
    int shap(int length, int breadth) { return area = length * breadth; }
};

int main() {
    shape* s;
    square sq;
    rectangle rect;

    s = &sq;
    s->shap(4, 5);

    s = &rect;
    s->shap(6, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You returned before printing the values.

Comment: "Displayed on the screen"? How do you expect the program to know that you want something to be displayed on the screen? Nothing in C++ gets "displayed on the screen" by itself. It is you who are supposed to send things to the screen to be displayed. But you never do it in your code. That's why nothing is displayed.

Comment: Theses warnings happen because you should define a virtual destructor in base class shape, like: virtual ~shape(){};

Comment: @AndreyT- Okay,you are absolutely right. But where should i give the cout statement then- in the main or in the function definition?

Comment: cout << s->shap(6,3); should work.

Comment: @AngelKoh: on some systems the last line of output may be overwritten by the shell unless it's properly delimited with `'\n';` (i.e. `std::cout << s->shap(6,3) << '\n';`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not getting the desired output with this program. The warnings
>   that I am getting are:
>
> ```
> Class 'shape' has virtual method 'shap' but non-virtual destructor.
> lass 'square' has virtual method 'shap' but non-virtual destructor.
> Class 'rectangle' has virtual method 'shap' but non-virtual destructor.
> ```

To clear the warnings, it's exactly like what the warnings says.

add into the respective classes their destructor.

```
virtual ~shape();
virtual ~rectangle()
virtual ~square();
```

also for rectangle::shap and square::shap, add a virtual in front of it.

Comment: But why do I need to declare virtual destructors? and how does it help?

Comment: @user3012742: you don't and it won't, other than to silence the warnings (if you actually define them ala `virtual ~shape() { }` and not just declare them as per this answer).  The compiler is warning because the presence of a virtual function suggests some code may one day want to store dynamically allocated objects using base-class pointers, where upon `delete` via that base-class pointer won't work unless the destructor's `virtual`.

Comment: @AngelKoh "also for rectangle::shap and square::shap, add a virtual in front of it." - best practice for C++11 is to add [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) rather than `virtual`, and it's worth pointing out that any of these options makes no functional difference... `virtual` is just documentation, and `override` a compiler-check.

Comment: thankyou..i got the concept..also, how do i intilaise values using a constructor here?